# Rename/update a specific tag in all documents

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have these documents in a collection:

```
[{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57496afadc964de30a8084a1"),
    "name" : "MongoDB: The Definitive Guide",
    "tags" : [ "IT", "SQL" ]
},{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57496afadc964de30a8084a2"),
    "name" : "MongoDB Applied Design Patterns",
    "tags" : [ "SQL", "MongoDB" ]
}]
```

I need to rename all "SQL" tags to "NoSQL" in all documents. I can do it by first adding the new tag-name, and then removing the one that needs updating:

```
  db.getCollection('Book').update(
    { tags: 'SQL' },
    { '$push': { tags: 'NoSQL' } },
    { multi: true })

  db.getCollection('Book').update(
    { tags: 'SQL' },
    { '$pull': { tags: 'SQL' } },
    { multi: true })
```

But this requires two separate queries.

How can I achieve this with a singe statement?

Comment: Comment by @cubbuk: Beware that this will only update the first matched element in a document. So assuming you may have duplicate tags in a document such as  {tags: ["SQL", "Java", "SQL"]}, the above query will only update the first element. You can use $addToSet rather than $push to guarantee that there won't be duplicate tags in your documents.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using the wrong operators. You need to use the [`$set`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) operator and the [`$`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) positional update operator. Also you should be using [`updateMany()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/) because `update()` is deprecated in official language drivers.

```
db.getCollection('Book').updateMany(
    { 'tags': 'SQL' }, 
    { '$set': { 'tags.$': 'NoSQL' } }
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `$ operator` to update a particular element in a document, and using `multi` option you will update all matching documents.

```
db.getCollection('Book').update(
{ tags: 'SQL' },
{ '$set': { "tags.$": 'NoSQL' } },
{ multi: true })
```

Beware that this will only update the first matched element in a document. So assuming you may have duplicate tags in a document such as  `{tags: ["SQL", "Java", "SQL"]}`, the above query will only update the first element. You can use `$addToSet` rather than `$push` to guarantee that there won't be duplicate tags in your documents.